# Setting up the result directory except allure-results

Tags: jasmine, protractor, allure

I want to save the Results of allure in some other directory other than allure-results. However, even i changed the resutlDir to someother directory still its saving the result in allure-results directory.

```
    var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
        allureReport: {
            resultsDir: './allure/'
        }
    }));
```

Still results saved in allure-results. please let me know how this can be done.
do i need to make changes in Pom.xml file.

Comment: It should work from what I see in the project's source code and documentation. Are you sure you are executing the very same config you are posting? Also, what if you remove the `./` at the beginning?

Comment: Just a thought, please check if you have copied that block of code multiple times in your conf file mistakenly and last one is pointing to "allure-results" only.